# html flex components not combining in a flex: 1 0 auto layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have built a landing page with the below HTML.

I have also [carefully constructed a bootply](https://www.bootply.com/bYlAS71OWw), showing exactly how the pink `div` expands too far, and does not cover the screen as intended.

> **https://www.bootply.com/bYlAS71OWw**

I have a pink region that should resize to take up the available space filling the browser, but not creating a scrollbar.

It appears that the breadcrumb, and the heading are not being subtracted from the overall area used.

- `heading` is in a `col`, and is flex,
- `.breadcrumb` is flex.

The page creates scroller for the combined height of the the heading and breadcrumb.

```
<app-dashboard>
  <div class="app-body">

    <main class="main">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="#/">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
          <span tabindex="0">Property Locations</span>
        </li>    
      </ol>

      <div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <ng-component class="d-flex flex-grow w-100">
          <div class="row w-100">
            <div class="col">
               HEADING    
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-grow bg-pink-300 h-100 w-100">
              THIS SHOULD GROW, BUT NOT CREATE A SCROLLBAR
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-component>
      </div>
    </main>

  </div>
  <footer class="app-footer">
    <span>
      <a href="..."></a>Pander.</span>
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-code-fork"></i>
    </span>
  </footer>
</app-dashboard>
```

The CSS for flex-grow is:

```
.flex-grow {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please simplify the example (remove custom tags for example). I get only roughly what you are trying to achieve, but a few things first:

1. What grows and shrinks is flex item, not flex container. And an element only becomes a flex item when its immediate parent is a flex container. Your div with **bg-pink-300** is not a flex item because its immediate parent is just a **row**
2. It appears that you want to use flexbox to make your div automatically fill the available vertical space. But all your flex containers are horizontal containers, hence vertically you are really just relying on the percentage height.

Generally, your main container should be a vertical flexbox that defines the total vertical space which should not overflow. Your breadcrumb, header, and the pink div all go into this container as flex items. Breadcrumb and header do not need to grow or shrink, they should have flex: none. The pink div can be defined to have flex: 1 1 0 so that it grows and shrinks to obsorb whatever space within the main container after breadcrumb and header have taken their cut.

Comment: It took a while, but your direction was spot on. I think I have flex slightly taped now... there are a lot of idiosyncrasies though